# How to apply a function for each row of a dataframe, which checks keys of embedded dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My objective is to identify if there is a certain key inside the dictionary embedded in a cell of the dataframe and write the result in an additional column.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```py
d = {'symbol':['AMD', 'MSFT', 'BKI', 'UNH'], 'prices': [{'2010-01-04': 9.79}, {'2010-01-04': 30.62}, {'2014-05-06': 0.14}, {'2010-01-04': 31.38}]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('symbol')
```

```
| symbol |         prices        |
|:------:|:---------------------:|
| AMD    | {'2010-01-04': 9.79}  |
| MSFT   | {'2010-01-04': 30.62} |
| BKI    | {'2014-05-06': 0.14}  |
| UNH    | {'2010-01-04': 31.38} |
```

Then, I want to check if '2010-01-04' key exists inside the dictionary and I try to obtain the condition in a new column:

```py
if '2010-01-04' in df['prices'].apply(lambda x: x.keys()):
    df['Condition'] = df['prices'].apply(lambda x: True)
else:
    df['Condition'] = df['prices'].apply(lambda x: False)
```

But, I get this:

```
| symbol |         prices        | condition obtained | expected condition |
|:------:|:---------------------:|--------------------|--------------------|
| AMD    | {'2010-01-04': 9.79}  | False              | True               |
| MSFT   | {'2010-01-04': 30.62} | False              | True               |
| BKI    | {'2014-05-06': 0.14}  | False              | False              |
| UNH    | {'2010-01-04': 31.38} | False              | True               |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the conditioning for each cell in the col, i.e. the condition shall happen within the apply.

```
df['check'] = df.prices.apply(lambda x: '2010-01-04' in x)
```

What you are doing is following

```
print(df['prices'].apply(lambda x: x.keys()))
```

outcome

```
symbol
AMD     (2010-01-04)
MSFT    (2010-01-04)
BKI     (2014-05-06)
UNH     (2010-01-04)
Name: prices, dtype: object
```

and then

```
print('2010-01-04' in df['prices'].apply(lambda x: x.keys()))
```

outcome

```
False
```

and hence the if block is not being executed. Its going to the else block, and assigning `False` to all the values of the column `df['Condition']` (by the way of broadcasting)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple dates You can create a new column and use `isin` to find required keys :

```
df['key'] = df['prices'].apply(lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])

k = ['2010-01-04']

df['condition'] = df['key'].isin(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid using `apply` by convert `df.prices` to dataframe using `df.index` and using `reindex`. The general recommendation is only using `apply` at the last resort since it is going affect performance.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.prices.tolist(), index=df.index).reindex(['2010-01-04'], axis=1).notna()


Out[1441]:
        2010-01-04
symbol
AMD           True
MSFT          True
BKI          False
UNH           True
```

Using `join` to add it to `df`

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.prices.tolist(), index=df.index).reindex(['2010-01-04'], axis=1).notna())


Out[1442]:
                       prices  2010-01-04
symbol
AMD      {'2010-01-04': 9.79}        True
MSFT    {'2010-01-04': 30.62}        True
BKI      {'2014-05-06': 0.14}       False
UNH     {'2010-01-04': 31.38}        True
```